# How to extract a dynamic 2D grid of spatially localised gain values

Tags: matlab, 3d, grid, 2d, mesh

I have modeled a dipole antenna and struggled for several days with the documentation before asking my question. I would like to create a grid that runs from the origin of the reference frame to the point (maxWidth, maxHeight) and is located by a third coordinate. The user specifies the position of the antenna phase centre using x0,y0 and z0. So we can have a plane parallel to the axes either X/Y (constant z) or Y/Z (constant x) or X/Z (constant y). I run the grid with a defined step called `mesh_size`.

Here's my code :

```
x0 = 25.0;
y0 = 25.0;
z0 = 25.0;
frequency = 150000.0;
dipoleAntenna = dipole('Length', 3.0, 'Tilt', 90, 'TiltAxis', [0, 0, 1]); % Tilt vertical et polarisation autour de z
pattern(dipoleAntenna, frequency, 'CoordinateSystem', 'polar');
maxGridWidth = 50.0; % Largeur maximale en mètres
maxGridHeight = 50.0; % Hauteur maximale en mètres
mesh_size = 0.1;
num_divisions_width = floor(maxGridWidth / mesh_size);
num_divisions_height = floor(maxGridHeight / mesh_size);
planToDisplay = "X/Z";
thirdcoord = 25.0;
x_coords = 0:mesh_size:maxGridWidth;
y_coords = 0:mesh_size:maxGridHeight;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x_coords, y_coords);
valueMatrix = zeros(size(X));
for i = 1:length(x_coords)
    for j = 1:length(y_coords)
        if strcmp(planToDisplay, 'X/Y')
            z = thirdcoord - z0;
            x = x_coords(i) - x0;
            y = y_coords(j) - y0;
        elseif strcmp(planToDisplay, 'X/Z')
            y = thirdcoord - y0;
            x = x_coords(i) - x0;
            z = y_coords(j) - z0;
        elseif strcmp(planToDisplay, 'Y/Z')
            x = thirdcoord - x0;
            z = y_coords(j) - z0;
            y = x_coords(i) - y0;
        end
        r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2);
    
        if x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 0
            Eeff = 25001;
            valueMatrix(i, j) = Eeff;
        else
            [direct, ~, ~] = pattern(dipoleAntenna, frequency, 'Azimuth', atan2(y, x), 'Elevation', acos(z / sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)));
            Eeff = sqrt(30*10000.0*2.0*direct)/r;
            valueMatrix(i, j) = Eeff;
        end
    end
end
```

I've tried turning the antenna without changing the marker to change the cut without changing my variables, but I'm getting very strange results:

```
planToDisplay = 'Y/Z';
if strcmp(planToDisplay, 'X/Y')
    dipoleAntenna = dipole('Length', 3.0, 'Tilt', 0, 'TiltAxis', [0, 0, 1]); % Tilt vertical et polarisation autour de z
    disp(planToDisplay);
elseif strcmp(planToDisplay, 'X/Z')
    dipoleAntenna = dipole('Length', 3.0, 'Tilt', 90, 'TiltAxis', [0, 1, 0]); % Tilt horizontal et polarisation autour de y
    disp(planToDisplay);
elseif strcmp(planToDisplay, 'Y/Z')
    dipoleAntenna = dipole('Length', 3.0, 'Tilt', 90, 'TiltAxis', [1, 0, 0]); % Tilt vertical et polarisation autour de x
    disp(planToDisplay);
end
for i = 1:length(x_coords)
    for j = 1:length(y_coords)
        z = thirdcoord - z0;
        x = x_coords(i) - x0;
        y = y_coords(j) - y0;
[ ... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Antenna radioation pattern cuts or slices can be directly defined as inputs to the function `pattern`.

**1.-**

```
f = .15e6;    % [Hz]

dp = dipoleCylindrical; 
dp.Length=3   % [m]
dp.Tilt=90       % [degree]
dp.TiltAxis=[0 0 1]

figure(1)
show(dp)
```

[image]

figure(2)
pattern(dp,f);          % show 3D radiation pattern

[image]

**2.- Calculate 3D Directivity Azimuth Elevation**

```
[D,AZ,EL]=pattern(dp,f);
```

**D**irectivity

**AZ**imuth

**EL**evation

**3.- Calculate and show XY cut**

```
figure(3)
pattern(dp,f,0,1:1:360);    
[D1,AZ1,EL1]=pattern(dp,f,0,1:1:360);
```

[image]

**4.- Calculate and show YZ cut**

```
figure(4)
pattern(dp,f,0:1:180,0);         
[D2,AZ2,EL2]=pattern(dp,f,0:1:180,0);
```

[image]

While `dipoleCylindrical` generates a rod antenna, which is the one I assume you want, because of the `3m` length you mention, the command `dipole` generates a **MICROSTRIP dipole antenna**, an antenna **printed on PCB**.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer ! I was looking more for a solution with the ability to positionate my plan thanks to a thirdcoord, i think it is not possible with this ?